# Saving the state of checkboxes onclick

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

```
<form name="form_name" action="/" method="get">
          <% if params["title"].present?%>
            <% if params["title"] == "1" %>
            <input type="checkbox" name="title" onclick="this.form.submit();" value="1" checked> Title <input name="title" type="hidden" value="0" />
            <%else%>
            <input type="checkbox" name="title" onclick="this.form.submit();" value="1"> Title
            <%end%>

            <%else%>
             <input type="checkbox" name="title" onclick="this.form.submit();" value="1">Title
        <%end%> 
    <% if params["description"].present?%>
            <% if params["description"] == "1" %>
            <input type="checkbox" name="description" onclick="this.form.submit();" value="1" checked> Description <input name="description" type="hidden" value="0" />
            <%else%>
            <input type="checkbox" name="description" onclick="this.form.submit();" value="1"> Title
            <%end%>

            <%else%>
             <input type="checkbox" name="description" onclick="this.form.submit();" value="1">Title
        <%end%> 

    </form>
```

**GOAL**: Have checkboxes that submit onclick while preserving the state of other unmodified checkboxes

I have a bunch of checkboxes that submit the form when they are clicked.  They return to the same page when clicked, with new GET data.  The above code is kind of a hack and works for one checkbox.  But due to the way I did this, it doesn't work for multiple checkboxes.

This does not seem like the way to do it.  I believe that the right answer is to determine if a checkbox was checked or unchecked with javascript or jquery.  I'm not that comfortable with either of these so if someone could direct me in the right direction...

Comment: I guess this is asp, so I don't post an answer because I don't know asp, but you should use url parameters(GET parameters) like this: If there's a get param __element_name__ and it's true, then the same checkbox should be checked(do this right before outputting this checkbox)

Comment: @MNVOH, it is clearly tagged RoR.

Comment: can you please list the code for multiple check boxes?

Comment: updated.  the problem here is that the hidden field is different than the visible one, so I get something like /?description=1&title=1&title=0

Comment: @maximus Oops! My bad. Doesn't matter though, since I said, I GUESS, and proposed a general solution. :p

Comment: @MNVOH, you were at right direction. It's a tricky question but I got the solution.

Comment: Ok, good job, and thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

problem is redundant hidden inputs,

```
      <form name="form_name" action="/" method="get">
        <% if params["title"].present?%>
          <% if params["title"] == "1" %>
            <input type="checkbox" name="title" onclick="this.form.submit();" value="1" checked> Title 
          <%else%>
            <input type="checkbox" name="title" onclick="this.form.submit();" value="1"> Title
          <%end%>
        <%else%>
            <input type="checkbox" name="title" onclick="this.form.submit();" value="1">Title
        <%end%> 
        <% if params["description"].present? %>
          <% if params["description"] == "1" %>
            <input type="checkbox" name="description" onclick="this.form.submit();" value="1" checked> Description 
          <%else%>
            <input type="checkbox" name="description" onclick="this.form.submit();" value="1"> Description
          <%end%>

        <%else%>
           <input type="checkbox" name="description" onclick="this.form.submit();" value="1">Description
        <%end%> 
      </form>
```

They are meant to submit a zero value if check box unchecked, but good thing about browser is that, it will not submit unchecked check boxes and `<% if params["description"].present? %>` such conditions become false without checking it's value.

So more optimised code after removing such redundant conditions is,

```
      <form name="form_name" action="/" method="get">
        <% if params["title"] == "1" %>
          <input type="checkbox" name="title" onclick="this.form.submit();" value="1" checked> Title 
        <%else%>
          <input type="checkbox" name="title" onclick="this.form.submit();" value="1"> Title
        <%end%>

        <% if params["description"] == "1" %>
          <input type="checkbox" name="description" onclick="this.form.submit();" value="1" checked> Description 
        <%else%>
          <input type="checkbox" name="description" onclick="this.form.submit();" value="1"> Description
        <%end%>
      </form>
```